# Axis label is not displayed and adding labels to stacked bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, axis, missing

I have made this stacked bar chart but I can't get my **x-axis** label to be shown even though I have added them in the codes. Also, can anyone tell me how can I add labels to my stacked bar chart like in the picture ? Thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    legend style={
    legend columns=4,
        at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},
        anchor=north,
        draw=none
    },
    xlabel= Percentage,
    ylabel= Environmental indicators,
    ytick=data,
    xtick=data,
    axis y line*=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    width=.9\textwidth,
    bar width=6mm,
    yticklabels={GWP, ODP, POCP, AP, EP(T), EP(FW), EP(M), ADP, CED},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=100,
    area legend,
    y=8mm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.625},
]
\addplot
[Construction,fill=Construction] 
coordinates
{(7.9,0) (8.8,1) (20.2,2) (28.7,3) (20.5,4) (44.7,5) (17.8,6) (46.6,7) (3.9,8)};
\addplot
[Operational,fill=Operational] 
coordinates
{(89.7,0) (89.5,1) (76.3,2) (64.5,3) (76.3,4) (50.1,5) (70.5,6) (37.9,7) (95.4,8)};
\addplot
[Maintenance,fill=Maintenance] 
coordinates
{(1.0,0) (1.5,1) (2.8,2) (6.4,3) (2.9,4) (4.8,5) (3.1,6)(15.3,7) (0.6,8)};
\addplot
[Disposal,fill=Disposal] 
coordinates
{(1.3,0) (0.2,1) (0.7,2) (0.3,3) (0.3,4) (0.5,5) (8.6,6)(0.1,7) (0.1,8)};

\legend{Construction, Operational, Replacement, Disposal}
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Life cycle phase contribution analysis per impact category.\\Categories from bottom to the top are Global Warming Potential (\ac{GWP}), Ozone Depletion Potential (\ac{ODP}), Photochemical Ozone Creation Potential (\ac{POCP}), Acidification Potential (\ac{AP}), Terrestrial Eutrophication Potential \ac{EP(T)}, \ac{EP(FW)}, \ac{ADP} and \ac{CED}.}
\label{conventional}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301).  But, please edit your code so that it produces the erroneous result that you describe. As it is, it is _not_ compilable. For instance you have `\[` where it should just be a `[` for optional parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope it's correct now.

Comment: Did you try compiling it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's the mistake here because I extracted the table from my thesis and it's not exactly the whole thing. Did i miss any package that you can kindly enlighten me on?

Comment: I get errors when I compile this.Please put this in a separate document and make sure it compiles.  For instance, the `Construction` style is not defined, neither is the `Construction` color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is somewhat hard to write an answer because this requires some fair amount of avoidable extra work. I ended up defining the missing colors somehow, and inventing a command `\ac`. Now to your questions:

1. You cannot see the `xlabel` since you put the legend on top. I moved the legend down.
2. You can add numbers with percentages using `nodes near coords`. I made a guess which numbers you might be after, and of course this guess is most likely wrong, but perhaps will allow you to modify things in such a way that you get what you want.

Result

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\definecolor{Construction}{RGB}{184,36,33}
\definecolor{Operational}{RGB}{233,171,100}
\definecolor{Maintenance}{RGB}{124,174,255}
\definecolor{Disposal}{RGB}{185,220,165}
\newcommand{\ac}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[clip=true,
    xbar stacked,
    legend style={
    legend columns=4,
        at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},yshift=-5mm,
        anchor=north,
        draw=none
    },
    ytick=data,
    xtick=data,
    axis y line*=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xlabel= Percentage,
    ylabel= Environmental indicators,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    width=.9\textwidth,
    bar width=6mm,
    yticklabels={GWP, ODP, POCP, AP, EP(T), EP(FW), EP(M), ADP, CED},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=100,
    area legend,
    y=8mm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.625},
    visualization depends on=x \as \rawx,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
    every node near coord/.style={xshift=\rawx*1.5pt+0.5cm,text=white},
]
\addplot
[Construction,fill=Construction] 
coordinates
{(7.9,0) (8.8,1) (20.2,2) (28.7,3) (20.5,4) (44.7,5) (17.8,6) (46.6,7) (3.9,8)};
\addplot
[Operational,fill=Operational,nodes near coords={}] 
coordinates
{(89.7,0) (89.5,1) (76.3,2) (64.5,3) (76.3,4) (50.1,5) (70.5,6) (37.9,7) (95.4,8)};
\addplot
[Maintenance,fill=Maintenance,nodes near coords={}] 
coordinates
{(1.0,0) (1.5,1) (2.8,2) (6.4,3) (2.9,4) (4.8,5) (3.1,6)(15.3,7) (0.6,8)};
\addplot
[Disposal,fill=Disposal,nodes near coords={}] 
coordinates
{(1.3,0) (0.2,1) (0.7,2) (0.3,3) (0.3,4) (0.5,5) (8.6,6)(0.1,7) (0.1,8)};
\legend{Construction, Operational, Replacement, Disposal}
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Life cycle phase contribution analysis per impact category.
Categories
from bottom to the top are Global Warming Potential (\ac{GWP}), Ozone Depletion
Potential (\ac{ODP}), Photochemical Ozone Creation Potential (\ac{POCP}),
Acidification Potential (\ac{AP}), Terrestrial Eutrophication Potential
\ac{EP(T)}, \ac{EP(FW)}, \ac{ADP} and \ac{CED}.}
\label{conventional}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]